# Error on getValue

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have written this class. This is not complete description of original class to make my problem statement concise i am giving what is required

```
template < class T>  
class RB
{  
class Child  
{  
members are Child are  
  T getValue() const , Child* getRightChild() const , Child* getLeftChild() const ,  void setLeftChild(Child *i_leftChild) , void setRightChild(Child *i_rightChild)  
}  
//Problematic function   
void levelOrder(Child *root);  
};
```

Can you point out why my compiler is saying `"137 getValue' has not been declared "`

```
template < typename T>  
void RB< T>::levelOrder(Child *root)  
{  
     std::vector< RB< int>::Child* > vec1 , vec2;  
     vec1.push_back(root);  
      vector< RB< int>::Child* >::iterator vec1start ,vec1end , vec2start, vec2end;  
     while(vec1.size() != 0 && vec2.size() != 0 )  
     {  
         vec1start = vec1.begin();  
         vec1end = vec1.end();  
         for( ; vec1start != vec1end ; ++vec1start)  
         {  
          std::cout<<"\n node value = "<< vec1start->getValue();
```

I think i have not defined vector also correctly, my vector needs to hold inner class element, any help with that is also appreciated

Comment: Check the code formatting (select and ctrlk+k) it will make your code legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are not initializing `vec1start`.  Also, why is `RB` a template if you never use the template argument and only ever use `RB<int>`?  The error you get is because `vec1start` is an iterator which when dereferenced returns a pointer; thus, you need to do `(*vec1start)->getValue()` to do what you want.

Comment: vec1start is intialized to vec1.begin(). Thanks for help as it solved my compilation error.